# Code activates all Switches at once. I only need one switch at a time

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-navigation

I keep running into a error, i am new to react native. Someone give a possible fix?

```
    import React from 'react'
    import {StyleSheet, View,Text, Switch, Button, Alert, ScrollView, FlatList, SafeAreaView} from 'react-native'
    
    export default () => {
        const [isSwitchEnabled, setSwitch] = React.useState(false)
        const toggleSwitch = () => setSwitch(previousState => !previousState);
        const DATA = [
            {
                id: '1',
                title: 'Toggle Night Mode',
                switch: false
            },
            {
                id: '2',
                title: 'Remind me to take a break',
                switch: false
            },
            {
                id: '3',
                title: "Remind me when it's bedtime",
                switch: false
            },
    
        ];
    
        function Item({title}){
            return (
                <View>
                    <Text style={styles.text}> {title} </Text>
                    <Switch 
    
                    onValueChange= {toggleSwitch}
                    trackColor={{ false: "#767577", true: "#81b0ff" }}
                    thumbColor="#f5dd4b"
                    ios_backgroundColor="#3e3e3e"
                    value= {isSwitchEnabled}
                    />
                </View>
            )
        }
    
    
    
    
        function Header(){
            return(
                <View style = {styles.header}>
                    <Text style={styles.headertext}>Settings</Text>
                </View>
            )
        }
        
        return (
            <>
            <View>
                <SafeAreaView style ={styles.container}>
                    <FlatList
                        data = {DATA}
                        keyExtractor = {item => item.id}
                        renderItem = {( {item} ) => <Item title = {item.title}/> }
                        ListHeaderComponent = {Header()}
                    />
                </SafeAreaView>
            </View>
            <View> 
                <Button 
                title = "Clear Search History" 
                color = "#6fb6f0"    
                onPress = {() => Alert.alert('Food History Has Been Cleared!')}
                />
            </View>
            <View> 
                <Button 
                title = "Logout" 
                color = "#6fb6f0"    
                onPress = {() => Alert.alert('Successfully Logged Out!')}
                />
            </View>
    
            </>
        
        );
    }
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
        },
        text: {
            fontSize: 20,
            fontWeight: "300"
        },
        headertext: {
            fontSize: 30,
            fontWeight: "300"
        },
        header:{
            flex:1,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            padding: 10,
            backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5'
        }
    })
```

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Wysa.jpge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Wysa.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
import React from 'react'
import {StyleSheet, View,Text, Switch, Button, Alert, ScrollView, FlatList, SafeAreaView} from 'react-native'
    
    export default () => { 

    // use data set in default state
    const [data, setData] = React.useState([
            {
                index: 1,
                title: 'Toggle Night Mode',
            },
            {
                index: 2,
                title: 'Remind me to take a break',
            },
            {
                index: 3,
                title: "Remind me when it's bedtime",
            },
    
        ]);

        function toggleSwitch(value, index){

      const newData = [...data];
      const newData[index].isEnable = value;
      setData(newData);

    }

        function Item({item, index}) {
            return (
                <View>
                    <Text style={styles.text}> {item.title} </Text> // use `title` here like this
                    <Switch    
                        .....
                        value={item.isEnable || false} // change here
                        onValueChange={(value) => toggleSwitch(value, index) } // change here
                    />
                </View>
            )
        } 
        
        return (
            <>
            <View style = {styles.container}>
                <FlatList
                    data = {data}
                    keyExtractor = {item => item.id}
                    renderItem = {({ item, index }) => <Item item={item} index={index} /> } // send `item` as prop
                />

            </View>    
            </>
        
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attaching each item with one state, so all of your items are changing according to that state change. To fix it make each item a component with an internal state to control it, or create dynamically a different state for each item in your data object. You have to create a different state for each item.

Comment: Thank You, but could you guide me on how to change the value of the useState hook to be an array? Or how to make each item a component?

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```js
const Item = ({ data }) => {
  const [isSwitchEnabled, toggleSwitch] = React.useState(data.switch)

  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={styles.text}> {data.title} </Text>
      <Switch
        onValueChange={() => toggleSwitch(!isSwitchEnabled)}
        trackColor={{ false: "#767577", true: "#81b0ff" }}
        thumbColor="#f5dd4b"
        ios_backgroundColor="#3e3e3e"
        value={isSwitchEnabled}
      />
    </View>
  )
}

export default () => {
  const DATA = [
    {
      id: '1',
      title: 'Toggle Night Mode',
      switch: false
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      title: 'Remind me to take a break',
      switch: false
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      title: "Remind me when it's bedtime",
      switch: false
    },

  ];


  function Header() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Text style={styles.headertext}>Settings</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }

  return (
    <>
      <View>
        <SafeAreaView>
          <FlatList
            data={DATA}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            renderItem={({ item }) => <Item data={item} />}
            ListHeaderComponent={Header()}
            contentContainerStyle={styles.container}
          />
        </SafeAreaView>
      </View>
      <View>
        <Button
          title="Clear Search History"
          color="#6fb6f0"
          onPress={() => Alert.alert('Food History Has Been Cleared!')}
        />
      </View>
      <View>
        <Button
          title="Logout"
          color="#6fb6f0"
          onPress={() => Alert.alert('Successfully Logged Out!')}
        />
      </View>

    </>

  );
}
```